# Can't access wp-admin with virtual host

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, virtualhost, vhosts

I have a problem with my WordPress website. It runs perfectly on localhost but when I try to add a virtual host to it, I can't access the admin panel. I am using xampp.

I have tried to access it by typing `http://localhost/commerce/wp-admin` and `me.commerce.loc/wp-admin` in the search bar but none of those work. Both return `Oops! That page can’t be found.`.

Here is the code I wrote in my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/commerce"
    ServerName webmaster.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My code in `hosts` file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost 
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       me.commerce.loc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also override `siteurl` and `homeurl` in `wp-config.php`.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://me.commerce.loc');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://me.commerce.loc');
```

Please this post for more detail https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214580498-How-do-I-change-the-WordPress-Site-URL-

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research and it turns out I had to change `siteurl` and `home` fields in my `wp_options` table. After setting them to my v-host address it works perfectly.